# Get networkx subgraph containing a certain number of nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have a networkx DiGraph and I want to extract the subgraph that contains a certain number of nodes.
For example, the Digraph is 0-1-2-3-4-5. I want to obtain all the subgraphs that contains 3 nodes. The result should be: 0-1-2, 1-2-3, 2-3-4, 3-4-5.
How can I do that?

Comment: Here is my graph utility function for Ruby. Thought I had one for Python but can't find it. Python graphs are pretty similar.  Take a look at the last method, `vertex_subset`. Not sure if it's going to be overly useful for NetworkX though, as it just uses Dictionaries. https://gist.github.com/MyklClason/fe603a6005a1dedc6ec65fda7ff47f68

Comment: If you show us your attempt in Python, you are more likely to get responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understand correctly: Your example implies that you only want *connected* subgraphs? In a directed graph there's more than one kind of connectivity (weak and strong). So you have to decide which one you're looking for.

This might work:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

# The graph in your example (as I understand it)
G = nx.DiGraph((i, i+1) for i in range(5))

num_of_nodes = 3 # Number of nodes in the subgraphs (here 3, as in your example)
subgraphs = [] # List for collecting the required subgraphs
for nodes in combinations(G.nodes, num_of_nodes):
    G_sub = G.subgraph(nodes) # Create subgraph induced by nodes
    # Check for weak connectivity
    if nx.is_weakly_connected(G_sub):
        subgraphs.append(G_sub)
```

`combinations(G.nodes, num_of_nodes)` iterates over all unique combinations of `num_of_nodes` many nodes from `G`.

The selected subgraphs are exactly the ones you mentioned:

```
print([H.nodes for H in subgraphs])
print([H.edges for H in subgraphs])
```

shows

```
[NodeView((0, 1, 2)), NodeView((1, 2, 3)), NodeView((2, 3, 4)), NodeView((3, 4, 5))]
[OutEdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2)]), OutEdgeView([(1, 2), (2, 3)]), OutEdgeView([(2, 3), (3, 4)]), OutEdgeView([(3, 4), (4, 5)])]
```

If your graph is

```
G = nx.DiGraph([(i, i+1) for i in range(5)] + [(i+1, i) for i in range(5)])
```

and you're looking for strong connectivity then you have to use

```
...
    # Check for strong connectivity
    if nx.is_strongly_connected(G_sub):
        ...
```

(The usual warning: `G.subgraph()` only gives you a *view*.)

Comment: How to do the same for an undirected graph?

Comment: @AbdullahAsh-Saki Have a look [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.is_connected.html). So replacing `nx.is_weakly_connected(G_sub)` with `nx.is_connected(G_sub)` should work for undirected graphs.